# how to use "where in" clause

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class AgencyPosition(models.Model):
   Agency=models.ForeignKey(Agency)
   Users=models.ManyToManyField(User)
   PositionTypeCode=models.ForeignKey(PositionType)
   PhoneNumber=models.CharField(max_length=50)
   Email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
   StatusTypeCode=models.ForeignKey(StatusType)

class News(models.Model):
   Category=models.ForeignKey(Category)
   Title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Description=models.TextField()
   created_by=models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False)
   ActionDate=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,editable=False)
```

I wanna when user enter the name of an Agency I select top 5 news belong to specific agency.News model have an created_by field.created_by field is the user that insert that News.in AgencyPosition I determine user belong to which Agency.

I do this in views.py:

```
agn=Agency.objects.filter(Name=key)
AgencyPositionList=AgencyPosition.objects.filter(Agency=agn)
```

now I have all users from the specific Agency.then I wanna select News that their Created_by field is for that specific Agency.some thing like this pseudo code:

```
select top 5 * from News where created_by in(AgencyPositionList.Users)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
News.objects.filter(created_by__agency_position__id=your_agency_id)[:5]
```

Comment: this was my answer:top5news=News.objects.filter(User__agencyposition__Agency__id=myagency.id).order_by('-ActionDate')[:5]

Answer (score 2):

`News.objects.filter(created_by__in = AgencyPositionList.Users)[:5]`. It's all [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups).

Comment: I tried this.but had this error:'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Users'

Comment: @Asma: Do `AgencyPosition.objects.get` instead of `AgencyPosition.objects.filter`.

Comment: @Asma: Well, that's a data problem.